# How to use the `Animate.css` to the `angular` app?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to apply the animation  `bounceInUp` using the `animate.css`. on the div on show, But nothing works for me?

what the correct way to use this?

here is my css code :

```
.showing.ng-enter{
  animation:bounceInUp 1s;
}
```

my HTML :

```
 <p>Hello {{name}}!</p> <button ng-click="showIt()">Show</button>
    <button ng-click="hideIt()">Hide</button>
    <div ng-if="show" class="showing" >I am showing something here</div>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qgxN3kUTHqkxQv4HAAmV?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `animated` class with `showing`

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="show" class="animated showing" >I am showing something here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.showing {
   animation: bounceInUp 1s;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/lZmOfAnaumrdouN1du74?p=preview)**